# display:inline; isn't working When I use it on my list

Tags: html, list

I am trying to make my list horizontally and I saw that I need to type: display:inline; inside style argument but when I tried it, it didn't work. I will attach my code here maybe I did something wrong. thanks for the helpers!

```
<body style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:20px">
    <center>
    <img src="Images/Logo.jpg" style ="margin-top:100px; border:5px solid black;" alt="GameReview" title="Game Review"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul style="list-style-type:none; display:inline;">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">On me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Links</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Conatact me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</body>
```

this is for a school project.

Comment: The list items (`<li>`) are not inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline style needs to be on the `li` element.

```
<style>
  ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I forgot to do so. here